# Searching content of HBase table

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I need a help in searching HBase content. I have an HBase table 'tblsearch'.

How can I see the table schema (e.g. we do show create table tbl_name in MySQL)?
How can I see all content of table 'tblsearch' where ali value =24146 where date = '2014-02-08'

```
hbase(main):026:0> describe 'tblsearch'
DESCRIPTION                                                                                               ENABLED
 {NAME => 'tblsearch', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'd', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'NON true
 E', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '3', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL    => '-
 1', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'false', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', ENCODE_ON_DISK => 'tr
 ue', BLOCKCACHE => 'false'}]}
1 row(s) in 0.1040 seconds

Scanning 5 rows from the table:

hbase(main):023:0> scan 'tblsearch', {'LIMIT'=>5}
ROW                                      COLUMN+CELL
 a24146_1371760717_J=K\xF6               column=d:ali, timestamp=1379351295242, value=24146
 a24146_1371760717_J=K\xF6               column=d:level, timestamp=1379351295242, value=yellow
 a24146_1371760717_J=K\xF6               column=d:message_template, timestamp=1379351295242,     value=ALI {ali} has no user priority value
 a24146_1371760717_\xE1\xF7\x01\x0F      column=d:ali, timestamp=1379351295243, value=24146
 a24146_1371760717_\xE1\xF7\x01\x0F      column=d:level, timestamp=1379351295243, value=yellow
 a24146_1371760717_\xE1\xF7\x01\x0F      column=d:message_template, timestamp=1379351295243, value=ALI {ali} has no user weight vector
 a24146_1371760724_\x08\x18\xC20         column=d:ali, timestamp=1379351295243, value=24146
 a24146_1371760724_\x08\x18\xC20         column=d:level, timestamp=1379351295243, value=green
 a24146_1371760724_\x08\x18\xC20         column=d:message_template, timestamp=1379351295243, value=ALI {ali} has been successfully allocated
 a24146_1371817802_X\xD4`\x8A            column=d:ali, timestamp=1379351295361, value=24146
 a24146_1371817802_X\xD4`\x8A            column=d:level, timestamp=1379351295361, value=yellow
 a24146_1371817802_X\xD4`\x8A            column=d:message_template, timestamp=1379351295361, value=ALI {ali} has no user priority value
 a24146_1371817802_\xD97\xBBe            column=d:ali, timestamp=1379351295362, value=24146
 a24146_1371817802_\xD97\xBBe            column=d:level, timestamp=1379351295362, value=yellow
 a24146_1371817802_\xD97\xBBe            column=d:message_template, timestamp=1379351295362, value=ALI {ali} has no user weight vector
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any column as **date** here. But you could achieve that with the help of HBase filters. **For example,** if you want to fetch all the rows where **ali=24146** you could do this :

> hbase(main):001:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
>
> hbase(main):002:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SingleColumnValueFilter
>
> hbase(main):003:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.BinaryComparator
>
> hbase(main):004:0> import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter
>
> hbase(main):005:0> scan 'tblsearch', { FILTER =>
>   SingleColumnValueFilter.new(Bytes.toBytes('d'), Bytes.toBytes('ali'),
>   CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),
>   BinaryComparator.new(Bytes.toBytes('24146')))}

HTH

Comment: How can I filter using HBase shell? using scan or get?

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I search all level with value = orange with latest timestamp. I did this but didn't work: hbase(main):005:0> scan 'tblsearch', { FILTER => SingleColumnValueFilter.new(Bytes.toBytes('d'), Bytes.toBytes('level'), CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'), BinaryComparator.new(Bytes.toBytes('orange')))}

Comment: Looks OK to me. What's the error which you are getting?

Comment: yes it works. Thank you. How can i only see only those rows that has been entered in table yesterday or any particular day? Can i filter by timestamp to see data entered yesterday?

Comment: You can do that with the help of TimestampsFilter.

Comment: Could you please show how to use TimestampsFilter? I am new to HBase. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can see all content of table 'tblsearch' where ali value =24146 where date = '2014-02-08' based on rowkey of 'tblsearch" table defined or used while putting record in table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command in HBase Shell. Requires no imports and works for me in  0.94.6

```
scan 'tblsearch',FILTER=>"SingleColumnValueFilter('d','ali',=,'binary:24146') AND TimestampsFilter(1391167399643)"
```

Comment: How do I define the timestamp range in your query? I tried below but don't work? scan 'tblsearch', {FILTER=>"SingleColumnValueFilter('d','ali',=,'binary:24146')" AND TIMERANGE => [1391997389000, 1392256589000]}

Comment: Try this :  `scan 'tblsearch', FILTER=>"SingleColumnValueFilter('d','ali',=,'binary:24146')", TIMERANGE => [1391997389000, 1392256589000]`